# ArrayList as a n implementation of List in Java 8

Tags: java-8

You use a java.util.ArrayList as the implementation for a java.util.List collection using:

List L = new ArrayList();

Referring to the scenario above, what happens when you add an element that exceeds the ArrayList's capacity?

Comment: The capacity is increased automatically.

Comment: Never use raw types.

Comment: I'll keep in mind. Thanks.

Comment: It’s all in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html): “*As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically*”. Winners read documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several scenarios to your question:

#### You have enough memory to hold both the original array and a larger copy

Then it's the usual scenario, the capacity is automatically increased and you can add more elements.

#### You have few heap memory at your disposal.

In that case, you'll get an `OutOfMemoryError` when `ArrayList` tries to create a copy of its internal array with a bigger capacity.

#### You already have a capacity around `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8` and you have enough heap memory to create an even bigger array.

Then, you'll get an `OutOfMemoryError` if you're using a Hotspot/OpenJDK JVM. It's not documented anywhere in the `List` interface or their implementations, but according to tests [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) realized (see comments), this is what you get because creating an array of size `Integer.MAX_VALUE` throws such error. Other JVMs might throw other exceptions or errors.

Comment: Before adding an element at `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1`, you need an `ArrayList` having a size of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which is impossible in OpenJDK, as arrays can’t have that size and an attempt to create an array of that size will cause an `OutOfMemoryError`, so you’ll never get to that point. The linked code even has a comment saying this: “*Attempts to allocate larger arrays may result in OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit*”.

Comment: @Holger You are right, but... what you quote is merely the explanation why they use `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8` (because it **may** throw an `OutOfMemoryException`), not a guarantee that the OOME **will** be thrown. I'll fix the only part that needs fixing in my answer (which I messed up without thinking).

Comment: Why should trying to add an element at `size+1` cause an `IndexOutOufBoundException` if `size` is not `Integer.MAX_VALUE`? FYI, I even verified it practically, that you never get an `IndexOutOufBoundException` at these large capacities. `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8` will be used as safe capacity when growing close to this threshold; once it has been reached, this code will use exactly `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as new capacity, which will always fail with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit` on HotSpot/OpenJDK.

Comment: @Holger Okay, I'll take testing for granted.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList's capacity depends on available heap memory.

In case no more heap space is available when calling **ArrayList.add**, an OutOfMemoryError will be thrown